# How to add a Processing PApplet in SWT

Tags: java, swt, processing

I have a problem when trying to add a `PApplet` into SWT, it turns up an empty window when it should just render the `PApplet`. I.e. the `PApplet` works by itself, but not in a SWT window.

I thought that just adding the `PApplet` into the frame should initially do the trick, using the SWT tutorial code in Eclipse. Apparently it wasn't so easy. Here's my code, where `MyPApplet` is a customized `PApplet`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
    Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
    PApplet pApplet = new MyPApplet();
    frame.add(pApplet);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: call me an idiot... what's a PApplet?

Comment: @arcticpenguin: PApplet is a class that processing.org uses as a window/applet frame. It subclasses java's Applet class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made this little guide on how to fuse Processing with SWT in Eclipse: 
http://christian.liljedahl.dk/guides/processing-and-swt-in-eclipse

I hope this solves it for you.

My "trick" is to have one window for the Processing stuff, and a seperate window with the UI in its own thread.

Comment: "404 Page not found"

Answer (score 2):

i think all you're missing is pApplet.init();
see the documentation for the class: http://dev.processing.org/reference/core/javadoc/processing/core/PApplet.html

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an alternative way to achieve that.
Using a Swing Component as an adapter, which likes:
add the PApplet into a JComponent like JInternalFrame , then embed this JComponent into the SWT Composite.

I've made some practices on that, and it works fine..

and also I've blogged some summary on this topic:
http://blog.csdn.net/godoorsun/article/details/6747589

(btw, this article is written in Chinese :(, maybe you can read it through Google Translator, but the example code on that article is easy to understand)

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This only works with Processing `2.2.1`<sup>1</sup> and not with `3+`<sup>2</sup>**

In OPs code, there are two missing statements:

- As [user176840](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2015261/1913655) said, it is needed to call to `pApplet.init()` before opening the shell
- Also, to set a `Layout` to the shell like `FillLayout`, `GridLayout`, etc, so something like `shell.setLayout(new FillLayout())`

Basic working code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
    Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
    PApplet pApplet = new MyPApplet();
    frame.add(pApplet);
    pApplet.init();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

<sup>1</sup> In my case, I was trying to embed an applet into Maven based SWT project, so I can only use the last (and only) Processing version available for 2.X series in `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.processing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

<sup>2</sup> The reason why Processing 3 is not compatible can be found [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes-in-3.0#things-that-may-break-your-2x-sketches) and [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/commits/master/core/README.md), basically a major restructure of the code. I tried to embed the Processing canvas into the SWT application unsuccessfully.